# Why does the execution order of tasks in clojure boot change?

Tags: clojure, function-composition, boot-clj

```
(deftask test1 "first test task" [] (print "1") identity)
(deftask test2 "second test task" [] (print "2") identity)
(boot (comp (test1) (test2)))
=> 12nil
(boot (comp (fn [x] (print "1") identity) (fn [x] (print "2") identity)))
=> 21nil
```

If I use `comp` on tasks, the execution order is from left to right. If I use `comp` on anonymous functions, the execution order is from right to left. How is this inconsistency reasonable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for that difference is that when you use `comp` with boot tasks is that they are not bare logic that gets composed but each boot tasks returns a function which will be invoked later and that function wraps another function which is passed to it (like in ring middleware).

With plain functions it works like this:

`(comp inc dec)`

produces a function which does following:

`(inc (dec n))`

In boot tasks are similar to ring middleware. Each task is a function which returns another function that will wrap the next handler from the pipeline. It works like that (not literally, it's simplified for readability sake):

```
(defn task1 []
  (fn [next-handler]
    (fn [fileset]
      (print 1) ;; do something in task1
      (next-handler fileset))) ;; and call wrapped handler

(defn task2 []
  (fn [next-handler]
    (fn [fileset]
      (print 2) ;; do something in task1
      (next-handler fileset)))) ;; and call wrapped handler
```

So when you do:

`(comp (task1) (task2))`

And execute such composed task it works as if it was:

```
(fn [fileset1]
  (print 1)
  ((fn [fileset2]
     (print 2)
     (next-handler fileset2))
   fileset1))
```

Because a function produces by `(task2)` will be passed to function produced by `(task1)` which will wrap the one from `(task2)` (and call it after printing `1`).

You can read more on boot tasks anatomy in [its wiki](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot/wiki/Tasks). It might be also useful to read on [ring middleware](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Concepts#middleware).

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is great!

Comment: Would you amend your answer to start with "this is the order of execution"? I'm still not sure, but I think `(comp (task1) (task2))` means `(task1 (task2))`?